# Java - Prevent Resize but keep adding text to JTextArea with JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have made a `JTextArea` in which I log some info(With an endless loop)
I have already set the Preferred Size and added it to a `JScrollPane`. After logging messages reach the limit of the `Jtextarea` they stop printing on the screen . I want then to keep printing (and the scrollbar getting smaller and smaller), pretty much like a CMD prompt does. This is necessary because I already have another `Jtextfield` below and a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t set a preferred size on the `JTextArea`. Set the preferred size of the `JScrollPane` instead.

Comment: It worked! Is there also a way not to require the user to move the ScrollBar to see what is more?

Comment: Well just tell it to scroll after you added some text. Or add a listener which performs the scrolling on each text change.