# JScrollPane: Vertical bar visible but not active

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am using following code to show vertical bar on `JTable`. Despite of it is active. I can't scroll down:

```
scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    table = new javax.swing.JTable(dtm);
    table.setName("table"); // NOI18N
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(dtm);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    table.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 190));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

Picture Added:

[image]

Comment: try changing `JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` to `JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`

Comment: No change in behavior at all

Comment: @ejay_francisco Picture added

Comment: Get rid of the setPreferredSize call

Comment: @MadProgrammer Love you Bro! You are not mad at all! Please make this as an answer so I accept

Comment: Just like [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18956547/2711488)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `setPreferredSize`, the `JViewport` is using to information to decide how much space is required it needs, which the `JScrollPane` is then using to decide if it needs to show the scroll bars or not

If you really, absolutely have to modify the viewable size of the table, can try using `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize`